# How to create a web-page looking exactly like a Python notebook?

Tags: html, css, templates, jupyter-notebook

I have a jupyter notebook that I want to share on Internet.

I will upload the *.ipynb file so that the visitor can download and run it, but I also wanted to show the notebook directly in a webpage.

Note : I don't want the reader to be able to actually RUN the notebook, I am just looking for an appropriate HTML / CSS / JS template or something similar. I assume the plots will just be pictures, which is fine

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<object>` tag to embed files in html. but iPython notebook file is not supported. So covert it using the [nbconvert.](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)